# Number of roots in a special system of equations

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Claim: Let $\{p_{1},p_{2},\cdots,p_{K}\}$ be a probability distribution, that is, $p_{k}\in (0,1)$ and $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{K}p_{k}=1$.

Then the following system of equations has AT MOST finite number of solutions. (The system may not have any solution at all.)
$$\begin{cases}
  p_{1}+p_{2}+\cdots+p_{k}=1=c_{1} \\
  p^2_{1}+p^2_{2}+\cdots+p^2_{k}=c_{2} \\
\vdots \\
  p_{1}^K+p_{2}^{K}+\cdots+p^{K}_{k}=c_{K} \\
\end{cases}
$$ where $c_{1},\cdots,c_{K}$ are constants.

I believe the statement is true, in fact, I believe the number of solutions is upper bounded by K!, but I cannot prove it. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recast these equations in terms of the [elementary symmetric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).  For example, $(p_1+...+p_k)^2=\sum{p_k^2}+2\sum_{i<j}p_ip_j$ allows you to solve for $e_2(p_1,\dots,p_k)$

The elementary symmetric functions functions give the coefficients of a polynomial whose roots are $p_1,\dots,p_k$.  For example $-e_1(p_1,\dots,p_k)$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}.$  Now the roots of the polynomial are unique, up to order, so there are at most $k!$ solutions, if all the roots turn out to be distinct.

Of course, some of the roots may not satisfy $0\le p_j \le 1,$ so there may not be any admissible solutions to the original system.

Comment: Saulspatz, I get your line of thinking, but can the recast be done necessarily?

Comment: Yes, it can always be done.  The [fundamental theorem on symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#The_fundamental_theorem_of_symmetric_polynomials) guarantees this.  I feel certain there's a standard way to do this (due to Newton?) in the instant case.  I'll try to find a reference.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of Newton's identities.  [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) explains the situation.  Note that you don't really care what the complicated formula is, it's enough to know there is one.